# Simple Java generics question

Tags: java, generics

I want to have a method which calculates the mean of a LinkedList of type Integer, Double and Float.

The problem is the `sum += i;` statement, since java says that the + operator isn't defined for type Object.

I could do a cast, but if the LinkedList was of type Float, for example, and the cast was to Integer, I would be not computing the correct mean.

What should I do? Thanks.

```
 public double mean (LinkedList<?> l)
 {
  double sum = 0;
  int n = 0;
  for (Object i : l)
  {
   n++;
   sum += i;
  }

  return sum / n;
 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't require a `LinkedList` because everything you do is iterating of the elements in `l`. Just use `Iterable<? extends Number>`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should restrict your list to [`Number`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html)s. That is the common superclass for `Integer`, `Float`, `Double` and other numeric types. It has no operators defined, only conversion methods to e.g. `double`, but that is enough for you here:

```
 public double mean (LinkedList<? extends Number> l)
 {
  double sum = 0;
  int n = 0;
  for (Number i : l)
  {
   n++;
   sum += i.doubleValue();
  }

  return sum / n;
 }
```

Comment: This whole `<? extends Number>` happened while I was off using Ruby.  What is this construct called?  Does this syntax  `LinkedList<?>` say we have a LL of unknown type, and `LinkedList<? extends Number>` is a LL of unknown types each guaranteed to be subclassed from Number?

Comment: and why not `LinkedList <Number>` ?

Comment: To answer your first question: Yes, using `LinkedList<?>` specifies a linked list containing elements of unknown type (they are at least objects) and `LinkedList<? extends Number>` may contain elments of any subtype of Number (and if nobody is doing strange reflection hacks, it gaaranteed). Why not using `LinkedList<Number>`? It ties the users of your api to a specific type. You can't pass in a `LinkedList<Integer>`. In fact there is no need to even required LinkedList, the best way would be to require an `Iterable<? extends Number>`.

Comment: @Tony, this is called a _wildcard with extends_. `LinkedList<? extends Number>` matches any list of a subclass of `Number`. I.e. it can be a `LinkedList<Number>`, a `LinkedList<Integer>`, a `LinkedList<Double>` etc. It is important to note that the latter are _not_ subclasses of `LinkedList<Number>` - that's why the wildcard is needed here.

Comment: @Willi, if you want to reflect to someone else's comment, it is recommended to include his nick preceded by a @ in your answer (e.g. @Tony) - otherwise he won't get notified about your comment.

Comment: @willi @Péter Török Thanks for the info!  I'll get to googling on it.

Answer (score 1):

The only option would be to generalize on `java.lang.Number`but it wouldn't actually help much as you can't unbox a Number to anything which can be applied to the primitive arithmetic operators. So you'll still have to check for each of the Number-types and call Number.doubleValue, intValue and so forth on the Number-object.

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T extends Number> double mean (LinkedList<T> l) {
  double sum = 0;
  int n = 0;
  for (T i : l)  {
    n++;
    sum += i.doubleValue();
  }

  return sum / n;
}
```

Comment: Looks extremely similiar to Peter's answer.

Comment: Aham... So clever... did you ever think i c&p the question snippet and edited it?

Comment: I did, but the only thing you edited is not adding any value to the answer proposed by Peter. Using a generic method with only one parameter is useless.

Comment: In fact, if you see the post time, i posted it before. Actually, 3 minutes before...

Answer (score 0):

In Java, generic collections are contravariant. This means that if you have parent class A and class B which extends A, then you cannot make something like `List<A> list = new LinkedList<B>();`.

But there is a possibility to allow this type of substitution: you can use a construction like `List<? extends A> list = new LinkedList<B>();`. For your case:

```
 public double mean (List<? extends Number> l)
 {
  double sum = 0;
  int n = 0;
  for (Object i : l)
  {
   n++;
   sum += i;
  }

  return sum / n;
 }
```

Comment: Won't compile. The + operator is not defined for objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of things to consider.

1. Allow Collection instead of only lists
2. You don't need a separate variable 'n', just use l.size()
3. Watch out for empty/null input